# How do I Create a Checkers board using the graphics module?

Tags: python, graphics, chessboard.js

Im trying to make a chessboard(checkers) usuing graphics module strictly. No Arrays etc.

```
from graphics import*

> > #Graphics WindoW
def graphics_window():
win = GraphWin('Checkers', 600, 600)
win.setBackground("white")
win.getMouse()
win.close()

> > #Make Checkers Board
def Checkersboard():`
```

Now I am strugling to started with the red & black board.

Comment: Can't use loops?

Comment: I hope you can use loops. Just nest two loops and modulo to alternate colors (if (i + j) % 2 == 0:).

Comment: Can you show me how with the nested loops iohans?

Comment: Added an answer and provided a screenshot. Feel free to experiment with the colors and sizes.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using nested loops and draw a square of alternating colors (x64). Your board was defined as 600x600, so I set the squares to 75x75 (600/8).

```
from graphics import *

def Checkersboard():
    win = GraphWin("Checkers", 600, 600)
    win.setBackground("white")

    for i in range(8):
        for j in range(8):
            if (i + j) % 2 == 0:
                color = "red"
            else:
                color = "black"

            square = Rectangle(Point(i * 75, j * 75), Point((i + 1) * 75, (j + 1) * 75))
            square.setFill(color)
            square.draw(win)

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()

Checkersboard()
```

[image: Red and Black Checker Board in Python]

Comment: can u create a checkers game?